# React Native: back button press handler to avoid going to previous screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react-native screen where I added a handler to detect back button press and only go back to the previous screen if the state variable creatingChat is false, the issue is the user can go back as normal even if creatingChat is false, which I check and it is 100%, why could this be happening?

Is this because I return true?

```
useEffect(() => {

const backAction = () => {

      if(!creatingChat)
      {
        navigation.goBack();
      }
      return true;
      
    };

const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      backAction
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

`creatingChat` always initiate state, I think it's always ***false***.

Another information:
All state value inside `useEffect` without dependency will always equal initiateState, so please add this state into dependency array, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   ..do stuff
}, [creatingChat]}
```